# Issue with WSO2 APP Manager1.1.0

Tags: wso2

I am trying to login to the APP publisher after creating a user and assigning the internal/Publisher role to it, but every time it gives me the error as

```
No Privileges to login. You do not have the permission to login to this application. Please contact your administrator and request permission.
```

The console error is

```
User does not have permission to access the publisher application.Make sure the user has the publisher role.
```

Comment: Can you check the permission provided to that role? Have you changed any permission for the `internal/Publisher ` role?

Comment: I downloaded the previous release of the WSO2 APP Manager 1.0.0, and this works without any extra effort.Still to try again with the 1.1.0 version.

Comment: No, It's working fine. I checked. You don't need any extra efforts other than creating user and assigning the role.

Answer (score 0):

If the user has the internal/publisher role assigned, logging in should be possible.

Can you please mention the exact steps you are executing and any other changes made to configurations.

However there is a known issue [1] where we can't use a new role with permission identical to that of the internal/publisher role.
If you are trying to use such a newly created role, you can try the workaround mentioned in [1]

[1] https://wso2.org/jira/browse/APPM-796